# How to encrypt files in a folder

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I'm making a program to encrypt all files in a folder to not encrypt files 1 by 1.

So, here is my code for the AES 256 encryption

```
public class CoreEncryption
    {
        public static byte[] AES_Encrypt(byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
        {
            byte[] encryptedBytes = null;

            // Set your salt here, change it to meet your flavor:
            // The salt bytes must be at least 8 bytes.
            byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
                {
                    AES.KeySize = 256;
                    AES.BlockSize = 128;

                    var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
                    AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
                    AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

                    AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(bytesToBeEncrypted, 0, bytesToBeEncrypted.Length);
                        cs.Close();
                    }
                    encryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }

            return encryptedBytes;
        }
    }

    public class CoreDecryption
    {
        public static byte[] AES_Decrypt(byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
        {
            byte[] decryptedBytes = null;

            // Set your salt here, change it to meet your flavor:
            // The salt bytes must be at least 8 bytes.
            byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
                {
                    AES.KeySize = 256;
                    AES.BlockSize = 128;

                    var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
                    AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
                    AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

                    AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(bytesToBeDecrypted, 0, bytesToBeDecrypted.Length);
                        cs.Close();
                    }
                    decryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }

            return decryptedBytes;
        }
    }
```

And this to start encrypting and decrypting files

```
public class EncryptionFile
    {
        public void EncryptFile(string file, string password)
        {

            byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
            byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);

            // Hash the password with SHA256
            passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);

            byte[] bytesEncrypted = CoreEncryption.AES_Encrypt(bytesToBeEncrypted, passwordBytes);

            string fileEncrypted = file;

            File.WriteAllBytes(fileEncrypted, bytesEncrypted);
        }
    }

    public class DecryptionFile
    {
        public void DecryptFile(string fileEncrypted, string password)
        {

            byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted = File.ReadAllBytes(fileEncrypted);
            byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
            passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);

            byte[] bytesDecrypted = CoreDecryption.AES_Decrypt(bytesToBeDecrypted, passwordBytes);

            string file = fileEncrypted;
            File.WriteAllBytes(file, bytesDecrypted);
        }
    }
```

So now, I want to enter a folder path, and that my encryption process crypt every files in that chosen folder. How can I do that ?

Comment: Why can't you just recursively loop through all the files?  Please edit your question to include what you've tried.  The encryption part is somewhat irrelevant here.  In saying that, your encryption code is rather flawed.  It can't encrypt files larger than 2GB and will be very slow due to you recalculating the key for the same password for every encryption operation.  You also derive the IV from the password which is very bad practice, use a random IV instead.

Answer (score 2):

Um....
Just like this? 
It works fine on (Windows10 pro x64 / Visual Studio 2017).

Good luck.

//! ----------------------------------------------------------------

```
    static void Test1()
    {

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\_test", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        EncryptionFile enc = new EncryptionFile();
        //DecryptionFile dec = new DecryptionFile();

        string password = "abcd";

        for (int i=0; i<files.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(files[i]);
            enc.EncryptFile(files[i], password);
            //dec.DecryptFile(files[i], password);
        }
    }
```